# Active clamp forward converter (High side and lowside) with synchronous rectification

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Please help me with the detailed description of Active clamp forward converter with synchronous rectification.I have   seen a lot of journals regarding this and   I am getting more confused when I read more        journals.

I need a simple but detailed explanation for the active clamp foward convertor.                Help me please and thanks in advance !

Comment: I Know a basic working principle but not able to figure out the working fully !

Comment: Have you tried googling those words? How about you link the best article and point out the bits that confuse you. Without knowing what confuses you SPECIFICALLY, it's just guesswork and the question will be likely closed. Consider this... Doctor, without understanding or knowing symptoms what is wrong with me and how can you make me better.